# Cydia Tweak Development - Header Compile Error

Tags: objective-c, ios, cydia, tweak

I am building a simple tweak with only the `Springboard.h` header included. I get this when making with Theos:

This is the compile error I get when building:

```
Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
Compiling Tweak.xm...
In file included from Tweak.xm:1:
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:22: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of                         ‘GSEventRef’ with no type
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:22: error: expected `;' before ‘_headsetDownEvent’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:56: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘opaque_pthread_t’ with no type
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:56: error: expected `;' before ‘*’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:64: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:64: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:64: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:102: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:102: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:102: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:103: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:103: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:103: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:107: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:107: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:107: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:108: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:108: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:108: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:110: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:110: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:110: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:122: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:122: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:122: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:130: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:130: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:130: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:131: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:131: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:131: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:132: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:132: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:132: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:133: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:133: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:133: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:145: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:145: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:145: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:147: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:147: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:147: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:148: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:148: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:148: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:149: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:149: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:149: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:150: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:150: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:150: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:151: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:151: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:151: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:152: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:152: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:152: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:153: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:153: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:153: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:158: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:158: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:158: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:165: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:165: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:165: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:202: error: expected type-specifier before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:202: error: expected `)' before ‘GSEventRef’
/opt/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:202: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
Tweak.xm: In function ‘void _logosLocalInit()’:
Tweak.xm:15: error: ‘MSHookMessageEx’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [Peel.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Does anyone know why it is giving me compiler errors with my imported headers?

Comment: What headers are you using? Dumped headers can be quite finicky at times.

Comment: I'm using Ryan Petrich's dumped headers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the headers you are using is that they include other private frameworks like GraphicsServices.  I don't believe Ryan Petrich intended for those to be use in tweak development. Try these instead, or dump them yourself using class-dump.
https://github.com/Fr0stDev/SpringBoard-iOS5-Headers

Good Luck!